# Android activity closes itself

Tags: android, screen, wakelock, powermanager

I want to make my home activity in WakeLock stage. I put the following code in onCreate

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    wl.acquire();
```

But it closes after 2 to 3 hours without any crash.What should I do to avoid this problem? I want to make my app wake all the time.What might be the reason for this problem?

Comment: I think the reason is that the system will overtake the action and ignores Your wakelock. That might be a security thibg of android, which I think it´s ok. But You can make a Screen Sleep service for example, which listens to Your screen if this is going off. Than, let the service unlock the screen again..

Comment: this is a good example: https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

Comment: @Opiatefuchs but the screen is not going to sleep. I just finishes my activity. What might be the reason?
 I am using infinite view pager in that activity.